# Excel VBA - CommentThreaded object is not available for use

Tags: excel, vba

Using Office 365, I'm working with an Excel sheet with lots of data and people have added both notes and threaded comments to several cells. Now I need to extract all those using VBA and put them in another sheet with another format, but I'm only able to extract the notes using the `Range.Comments` object. Whenever I try to use `Range.CommentThreaded` to extract the threaded comments, I get a "Run-time error '1004'". For some reason, the `CommentThreaded` object does not seem to exist.

I have tried to record a macro when I create a new threaded comment and it works. The created sub contains `Range("T93").AddCommentThreaded ("Test")`, but even when I try to run the newly created macro I get the same run-time error.

In the Object Explorer I can find the objects related to threaded comments if I select "Show Hidden Members", so the objects are there but I can't use them.

Any ideas to what I am missing? Any reference I need to add?

Comment: Hi Anders and welcome to SO! Can you show us a bit more of the code you are running? It's hard to tell what the problem could be without seeing it in context.

Comment: AFAIK that isn't properly implemented in VBA (yet).

Comment: If you right click on a cell and there are two options, "Add Comment" and "Add Note". then `Range("T93").AddCommentThreaded ("Test")` should work. "note" is the clasic cell comments, "Comment" is now the threaded comments

Answer (score 1):

AddComment still adds the old style comment. AddCommentThreaded doesn't work (as Rory said). If you open the object browser,AddCommentThreaded isn't there, if you set the object browser to show hidden members it is there but it is greyed out.
[image: Hidden range members]

You need a workaround. Add the coments as old style comments (AddComment), and when the VBA has completed go onto the Review ribbon, select Notes, Convert to Comments and select all, the threaded comments will appear.